# Do while loop is in infinite loop, doesnt prompt for cin second time through

Tags: c++

I need the program to act as a vending machine, keep running total and determine change if applicable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "A deep-fried twinkie costs $3.50" << endl;
    double change, n = 0, d = 0, q = 0, D = 0, rTotal = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "Insert (n)ickel, (d)ime, (q)uarter, or (D)ollar: ";
        cin >> rTotal;
        if (rTotal == n)
            rTotal += 0.05;
        if (rTotal == d)
            rTotal += 0.10;
        if (rTotal == q)
            rTotal += 0.25;
        if (rTotal == D)
            rTotal += 1.00;

         cout << "You've inserted $" << rTotal << endl;


        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.precision(2);


        } while (rTotal <= 3.5);

        if (rTotal > 3.5)
            change = rTotal - 3.5;


            return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comparing floats and doubles : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison

Comment: You need two different variables for the currently inserted coin, and the total amount.

Comment: Also you are currently checking in all cases if the letter that the user has entered is equal to 0 which is never true.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a couple things wrong. First, you need to have a variable to read the character of the option (the n, d, q, and D). You also need to use those letters as characters (i.e. `'n'` and so on). Then, you need to compare the option you read from the input with the character, not the total inserted. Finally, if the user has inserted $3.50 it wont need to iterate again, so the condition should be `rTotal < 3.5`.

Here's the code with the corrections:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "A deep-fried twinkie costs $3.50" << endl;
    double change, n = 0, d = 0, q = 0, D = 0, rTotal = 0;
    char op;
    do {
        cout << "Insert (n)ickel, (d)ime, (q)uarter, or (D)ollar: ";
        cin >> op;
        if (op == 'n')
            rTotal += 0.05;
        else if (op == 'd')
            rTotal += 0.10;
        else if (op == 'q')
            rTotal += 0.25;
        else if (op == 'D')
            rTotal += 1.00;
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.precision(2);
        cout << "You've inserted $" << rTotal << endl;
    } while (rTotal < 3.5);
    if (rTotal > 3.5)
        change = rTotal - 3.5;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to count the coins the user has inserted, then add the brackets to the if statements and add 1 to the corresponding variable if such coin was inserted.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting ready to lose hope on this project. You're a saint among men.